# Popular Vim alternatives?

Tags: vim, vi

Are there any Vi clones that are still in wide use today (besides Viper mode in Emacs ;)), other than Vim? If so, what are the pros/cons to using it instead of Vim?

Comment: Is there a specific reason to ask this? Is there some feature that you are missing in Vim? If there is, that may help you get a more specific answer.

Answer (score 8):

[Kate (KDE Advanced Text Editor?)](http://kate-editor.org/) has a Vi editing mode.

Answer (score 6):

It's not strictly a clone, but real [live no-kidding vi](http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net/) is available open-source now.  Also lots of sources and links to many versions on the [vi-lovers page](http://thomer.com/vi/vi.html).

Comment: For suggesting vi as an alternative to vim, which is a vi alternative...  Yup, upvoting for that alone. :)

(Plus, was good to see that the original vi is available now, after porting)

Comment: @Arafangion And here I always thought vi was just vim-unimproved...

Answer (score 2):

From the Vi Lovers Home Page - http://thomer.com/vi/vi.html#versions

I don't know what your requirements or expectations are, but Wikipedia has a great comparison page [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors) that should help you figure out which version is best for you.

Answer (score 2):

ActiveState Komodo has a vi mode too.

Comment: Note that the Komodo vi mode is incomplete - it does not support marks:  http://bugs.activestate.com/show_bug.cgi?id=68134

Answer (score 1):

I use Vim for all my editing except when I use Visual Studio. Fortunately there's the  [ViEmu](http://www.viemu.com) plug-in for Visual Studio. Unfortunately it is not free nor a complete Vim implementation, but it's not expensive either and it close enough for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Slickedit ($$$) has a very nice VI emulation mode. Vslick has other features that make it quite nice as a programmers' editor (e.g., dynamic tag generation instead of having to re-run ctags).

Answer (score 1):

QT Creator has 'fake vim' mode.

Answer (score 1):

[VILE](http://invisible-island.net/vile/)

Answer (score 1):

Sublime text has a 'Vintage' mode which replicates many vi/m commands.

Answer (score 0):

I used the vi-plugin in Eclipse a while and it is quite good. But since my colleagues don't have a clue about vi they ran in to problems when they were trying to edit on my workstation.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use `elvis` to satisfy my enhanced-vi needs, but can't really offer a comparison (other than that both are very good) because I switched to `vim` a couple years back for the sake of using something that was easier to find support for (if only because it's what everyone else uses).

Answer (score 0):

I often use nvi when I want a stripped down version of vi.
Not any real pros of using it instead of vim. More lightweight and doesn't load all the plugins I have with vim.

Vim still has lot more features (tabs, plugins, better multi-buffer support...).

Answer (score 0):

Yzis

The main website http://www.yzis.org/ is no longer functional. However, the source code can still be found on GitHub: https://github.com/chrizel/Yzis